# Rotating in Direction Most Efficient

Tags: java

I have 2 objects in a game, an enemy and a player, and the enemy rotates toward the angle that points towards the player. The problem is that when the player crosses over the line at 0 degrees, the target angle changes from positive to negative, causing the enemy to turn all the way around instead of turning the few degrees it should in the opposite direction. Here is my code:

```
l.velX=-Math.cos(Math.toRadians(l.angle));
l.velY=-Math.sin(Math.toRadians(l.angle));
m.x+=l.velX;
m.y+=l.velY;
if(Math.toRadians(l.angle)<Math.atan2((m.y-p.y),(m.x-p.x)))
   l.angle+=i.gameSpeed;
else l.angle-=i.gameSpeed;
```

Here's a crudely drawn diagram of what's happening:[image: crudely drawn diagram]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `Math.abs` for the angle comparison?

Comment: Check if the absolute value of needed degrees rotated to the left is smaller than the absolute value of needed degrees rotated to the right?

Comment: If turn angle is greater than 180°, use angle-360°

Comment: The enemy turns gradually. `Math.atan2()` always returns between -pi and pi, so the turn angle is never greater than 180. In the diagram, the turn angle is currently at 180, and the target angle is at -150 or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the signum of the z component of the cross product:

```
l.angle+=Math.signum(l.velX*(p.y-m.y)-l.velY*(p.x-m.x))*i.gameSpeed;
```

(if it turns towards the wrong direction, use `-=`, I have not really thought it through)